# I publish under a one-word name, which Google Scholar does not index. What can I do?

Tags: citations, authorship, google-scholar, personal-name

I publish under a single name (no last name). As Google Scholar does not recognise me as an author I face several issues with citation counts and wrong bibliographic data being available in Google Scholar. I have reported this issue several times through the contact us form for Scholar but I just get an automated response from them. What can I do?

Example: When you search my name in scholar, my papers appear not because I am an author but because I am a word in the paper. Google does not index me as an author. So, if some one cites my work as Abhishta et. al. Google has no idea who is being cited.

This situation is a different from the questions that are asked before on this forum as the former questions were discussing problems that journals require multiple names for an author but in this case, the publisher is fine with having a single name and the paper is already published. However there are problems with Scholar indexing the data of the paper.

[First author indexed by Google as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVObx.png)

[Actual authors of the paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wvw4.png)

Comment: Contact google scholar...

Comment: Have you already created a google scholar profile for you?

Comment: As far as I know, there are quite a few users on this site who have a single name. I think this is not an individual problem. And we do have quite a few Google Scholar related questions before . Vote to "Leave Open".

Comment: I did see that you have an article in arXiv by using Google Scholar. Would you please clarify what kind of issues you face?

Comment: Yes, some of the preprints of my articles are at arxiv. But in each case where I am the first author, google just skips my name when it indexes the publication. As a result, I miss citations and some people might also cite me using the wrong bibtex that is provided by google.

Comment: I have contacted scholar multiple times, but each time I get an automated response. @FuzzyLeapfrog I do have a google scholar profile: [link](https://scholar.google.nl/citations?user=wf3-3qwAAAAJ). If you look at the related versions of all papers, the problem will become clear.

Comment: @Abhishta So even though the publications are correctly assigned to your profile, If some searchs for one of the publications, your profile is not linked behind your author name. Is that your problem?

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog First I had to manually add the papers to my profile. But, that is not a big deal. When you search my name in scholar, my papers appear not because I am an author but because I am a word in the paper. Google does not index me as an author. So, if some one cites my work as Abhishta et. al. Google has no idea about who is being cited,

Comment: @scaaahu Issues related to publication names and citations are relevant, but I would suggest a broader focus. Does Web of Science or SCOPUS make similar mistakes? How do they get fixed?

Comment: @Abhishta It would improve the question to edit it, so that the content of relevant comments that clarify the problem are included in the question itself.

Comment: @aeismail Web of science doesn’t make the same mistake. Scopus has attributed a set of names to my profile. So if any one of the names appear on the paper, scopus attributes it to my profile.

Comment: Sadly, the virtual world hasn't caught up with the real world. If you are building such systems or have influence over them in any way, I'd suggest you consider this issue seriously and find a solution. There is at least one CS professor at MIT with a similar issue. The OP here might seek him out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have only one name shown in my ID card. How do I write my name (surname) in research paper or article?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83593/i-have-only-one-name-shown-in-my-id-card-how-do-i-write-my-name-surname-in-re)

Comment: @BurakUlgut Not a duplicate of that. This is asking about a practical consequence.

Comment: Not having a surname makes you a nonentity in many bureaucratic environments. You have the choice to waste a lot of time and energy on insisting, or just style yourself a surname. Use you existing first name if it really doesn't matter for you.

Comment: Use "Dr." as your first name.

Comment: @Karl but what can I do about the present papers? Its only google scholar that does not identify my name but Microsoft academic and scopus or ieee does not have any problems..

Comment: To the user who raised the close flag, did you read [this comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/112178/i-publish-under-a-single-name-google-scholar-does-not-index-my-name-what-can-i#comment295120_112178) **???**

Answer (score 4):

Google scholar is imperfect. It's based on an automatic parser, rather than human curation. I've seen it make all kinds of mistakes.

What can you do? You already have set up a profile that has the correct information. You can try contacting Google, but don't expect much from them. I doubt they have the resources to deal with everyone who contacts them with an issue. However, they are always improving their algorithm and this may get resolved.

The only other thing I think you can do is alter how your name appears on papers to conform to western expectations, as suggested in this question: [I have only one name shown in my ID card. How do I write my name (surname) in research paper or article?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83593/i-have-only-one-name-shown-in-my-id-card-how-do-i-write-my-name-surname-in-re)

Overall, I wouldn't worry too much about it. It is easy enough to find your publications online and any human reader will understand that you are mononymous.

Answer (score 1):

Dirty hack: write your papers under your one name, twice.  (Prince Prince)

Comment: This wouldn't really work for somebody who already has an established history of publishing under one name (Magneto).