# Using legal mononym only for publications

Tags: publications, conference, online-publication, personal-name

I don't use a surname, implying I just have my first name in all my legal documents, and I intend to keep it this way. I got my first accepted submission in a conference lately where I added my name in this format: (eg.) "Meredith - ". Now my name is appearing as "-" in the list of contributors on the submission website.
I don't wish to add a surname, how do I deal with this?
This work will be added to ACM Digital Library where they do add full names as far as I know.

(PS: I want to be cited with my first name only in my future work as well.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have only one name shown in my ID card. How do I write my name (surname) in research paper or article?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83593/i-have-only-one-name-shown-in-my-id-card-how-do-i-write-my-name-surname-in-re)

Comment: Also relevant: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/112178/68109